# agregar valores de una colección a otras usando una columna como referencia (PHP, LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel, array, collection

Estoy trabajando con php en laravel, en este caso tengo 2 colecciones de objetos, una de ellas se ve así:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "product x",
        "quantity": "100",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "codProd": "product y",
        "quantity": "200",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "product a.",
        "quantity": "30",
    }
]
```

y el otro se ve así:

```
[
    {
        "reference": 1,
        "quantity": "80",
    },
    {
        "reference": 2,
        "quantity": "50",
    },
]
```

Lo que necesito es mantener la primera colección pero sumando el valor de la clave de `quantity` de la segunda colección, usando la clave de `reference` como una relación con la clave id de la primera colección, el resultado final debería verse así:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "product x",
        "quantity": "180",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "codProd": "product y",
        "quantity": "250",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "product a.",
        "quantity": "30",
    }
]
```

entonces como puedo hacer esto?, cualquier guia o ayuda se los agradezco.

Comment: Eso son array de objetos "planos"? o son "colecciones" de Laravel, es decir coleccion de modelos?

Comment: @Pipe colecciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion `map` de la coleccion para ir por cada uno de sus elementos, y para cada uno buscando si en la segunda coleccion hay algun item con esa referencia y sumarle el quantity así:

```
    $coleccion1 = collect([
        [
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "product x",
            "quantity" => "100",
        ],
        [
            "id" => 2,
            "codProd" => "product y",
            "quantity" => "200",
        ],
        [
            "id" => 3,
            "name" => "product a.",
            "quantity" => "30",
        ]
    ]);

    $coleccion2 = collect([
        [
            "reference" => 1,
            "quantity" => "80",
        ],
        [
            "reference" => 2,
            "quantity" => "50",
        ],
    ]);

    $result = $coleccion1->map(function ($item) use ($coleccion2) {
        $item['quantity'] += $coleccion2->where('reference', $item['id'])->first()['quantity'] ?? 0;
        return $item;
    });

    echo json_encode($result);
    //[{"id":1,"name":"product x","quantity":180},{"id":2,"codProd":"product y","quantity":250},{"id":3,"name":"product a.","quantity":30}]
```

Comment: estoy obteniendo el siguiente error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: En que linea te saca ese error?

Comment: entonces alguna parte de tu pregunta no es correcta. Me dijiste que eran colecciones de modelos de Laravel... y así desarrolle la respuesta

Comment: en realidad son resultado de una query builder que realizo, pero de todas formas las convierte a colecciones con collect(), deberia funcionar

Comment: Por el error, depronto deduzco que los objetos son realmente objetos planos, por lo que depronto te podría funcionar cambiando la linea interna del map por esta: `$item->quantity += $coleccion2->where('reference', $item->id)->first())->quantity ?? 0;`

Comment: muy bien fue error mio, tu respuesta es correcta. ahora voy hacerlo para restar igual solo cambiando el signo.. pero hay alguna forma de comprobar si despues de restar si la cantidad es <=0 no tomar en cuenta ese objeto en la coleccion, MUCHAS GRACIAS